# Circuit protection - Is this sufficient?

Tags: circuit-analysis, protection

I have a situation where I need to test a PCB to make sure it is working correctly. This PCB has 2 power and 2 signal lines (and GND). The 2 power lines are 12V and 3.3V. The signals are all 3.3V.

Basically, I plug this board into my test jig, and a microcontroller checks all the signals are sending the correct stuff.

The issue I am having is the PCB placement company made an error and managed to short out the 12V to one of the signal lines. This completely took out the microcontroller of the test jig. This happened 3 times, which meant replacing the micro each time, before I managed to trace the exact cause.

Hopefully, this issue is now resolved, but it has shown me that it is possible this could happen again, so I want to put in some sort of protection circuit so if either of the signal lines are shorted to the 12V, the jig will be fine. The circuit I have come up with so far is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3x3Z9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This seems to work well. If there is a short between the 12V and any of the signals, it brings the inverting input of the comparator higher than the non inverting, and stops the signal passing through to the jig. I purposefully haven't included part numbers or values for anything as I am yet to get to the part selection phase.

My question is, will this circuit be sufficient to protect the test jig? Or is there something I am missing? Would perhaps some form of isolation be more appropriate?

Comment: You don't use a bed of nails or flying lead test on your boards?

Comment: Make sure the op-amp non-inverting input voltages do not violate any datasheet maximums, and resistors are used on Q1 and Q2 bases to set current. Also consider an [analog switch](https://www.ti.com/switches-multiplexers/analog/products.html).

Comment: @rdtsc you mean use the analog switch instead of the NPN/PNP pair? That's a good shout. Would you say this circuit is enough then? Won't need any isolation or anythign extra for protection?

Comment: @RonBeyer What do you mean? By bed of nails, I assume you mean test pins or something? Why would either of those suggestions help? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MCG [Bed of nails](https://hackaday.com/2019/02/09/test-pcbs-on-a-bed-of-nails/), you can use it to test for shorts between test points, hopefully you have one on your signal lines and supply lines. You could also use flying lead but those are more complicated/expensive. If this is a board problem, I might also suggest x-ray, but if you are finding the issue is always the same, you have a design problem or a board house problem. You can try moving things around to avoid that or a higher quality board house.

Comment: @RonBeyer Ahh I see what you mean. Yeah, we have a bed of nails thing and the above circuit will do the test for shorts and stop the signal line blowing the micro if its shorted to the 12V. That's the only destructive fail. We have told the company doing the component placement about it and the second run looks fine. But still want to protect against it just in case. I just need to know if my circuit is enough protection, or if more is required